# How to access the blob storage file using link created by a logic app workflow. create SAS URL by path URL not working

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am not able to use the generated link from this action to access the file I have uploaded to the blob storage.

I am able to only access the URL generated from the UI only. When I match the two URLs I can notice that the one generated from the logic app is missing half of the part.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing issue from my side got expected as results.
By removing  **Web Url** from the body of send email action i got the blob storage file using SAS link .

**Web url does not include total path for the file. Hence use shared access signature which will include url of the file and signature also**

- Created logicapp workflow as shown below
  [image]
  [image]
- In Get blob content action blob is taken as shown in below
  [image]
- In Create SAS URI by path action blob path should be List of files path .
  [image]
- In send an email action i have taken only Shared access signature and then i get complete URL to mail and i can download file from using that link as shown in below outlook images.
  [image]
  [image][image]

Comment: Thanks for the workflow. I got the link to the file now which works. One of the mistakes I was doing was I was filling in group flow Identifier as well in create SAS URI by path block.